# bottle error "critical error while processing request:" when launched from systemd

Tags: python-3.x, systemd, bottle

I have a server built on bottle that works great when launched from userland. The server appears on port 8088 and appears to be communicating to the outside world, but when I contact the app all I get is the very informative "Critical error while processing request:schema" which is the url of the app.
My systemd file is below:

```
[Unit]
Description=Survey Service
After=multi-user.target
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Type=simple
Working-directory=/home/ubuntu/survey
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/survey/server.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've found several articles related to the informative error message, but none related with systemd. As I said, the app runs perfectly when launched as user ubuntu in the project directory with the very simple command "python3 server.py" but seems to be missing... something when systemd tries to launch it.

Systemd reports the process is running and, as I said, I'm able to connect to the app... it just fails in an orderly fashion with this message, and I'm lost as to why. I suspect a permissions problem, but doesn't "user" and "Working-directory" take care of that? All files used by the app are in that directory or directories below it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently doing it the old fashion way works: set systemd to run a bash script as such:

cat /home/ubuntu/survey/server.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ubuntu/survey/
python3 server.py
```

Works just great. So my question now becomes one about systemd: what is the point of "Working-directory" if it does not actually set to that working directory?